We have five dice and want to get at least three 6's in three rounds, where you can reroll any non-6's. What's the probability of success?
Was thinking about the title question. The idea presented to me was to calculate the probability that you roll three or more 6's, i.e.
$$P(X \ge 3) = P(X=3) + P(X=4) + P(X=5)$$
Then we easily have
$$P(X=3) = {5 \choose 3} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) ^3 \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) ^2 \approx 0.03215$$
$$P(X=4) = {5 \choose 4} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) ^4 \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) ^1 \approx 0.00322$$
$$P(X=5) = {5 \choose 5} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) ^5 \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) ^0 \approx 0.00013$$
$$\Rightarrow P(X \ge 3) = .0355$$
Then they suggested we have the probability of failure is $p = 1 - P(X \ge 3) = 0.9645$. Then, the probability of failure over three rounds is $p^3 = (0.9645)^3 \approx 0.8974$. Then, simply do $1 - p^3 = 0.1026$ and this is our probability of success after three rounds. However, this approach seems flawed to me—specifically, I don't see how we're tracking the fact that you can "save" any 6's that you get. While working this out on a paper, I feel like there are many different situations. For example, let's say you get one 6 in the first round. Then, in the second round, all your calculations will only include four dice, completely changing the probabilities (for example, $P(X=2)$ in the second round given that you got a 6 in the first round would be $P(X=2) = {4 \choose 2} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) ^2 \left( \frac{5}{6} \right) ^2$ instead of what we calculated for rolling five dice). Is the way described to me truly the way to solve the problem, is my thinking wrong somehow? Any answers appreciated.

Probably the easiest approach is to observe that the five dice are independent, so for each die you can compute the chance it rolls a six by the time three rounds have passed. This effectively collapses the three rounds into a single round, at which point you can apply the single-round probability.

Are you saying that the approach given by my friend is correct? i.e., calculating the success after three rounds by just subtracting the probability of failing after three rounds?

When you have many dice, it is often good to imagine dice with different colors : you have 5 dice (red, blue, yellow, green, white) ... and now, you will narurally guess the good strategy (the strategy described by all other people)

Your friend would be correct if the choice each round was to reroll either all five dice or none of them. However, as you've written it, it's possible to keep just the sixes at each round without keeping the rest.
Fortunately, this means the five dice are independent, so we can compute the desired probability by reversing the order of operations of your friend's approach. Instead of computing the binominal distribution first and then the probability of failure of all three rounds, we compute the probability of a single die (not) rolling a six in three rounds, then put that into the binomial distribution. To wit:
The chance of a single die not rolling a six in three rounds is
$$\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^3 = \frac{125}{216}$$
Then, putting this into the binomial distribution, we have
$$P \left( X_3 = 3 \right) = \binom{5}{3} \left( \frac{91}{216} \right)^3 \left( \frac{125}{216} \right)^2 \\
P \left( X_3 = 4 \right) = \binom{5}{4} \left( \frac{91}{216} \right)^4 \left( \frac{125}{216} \right)^1 \\
P \left( X_3 = 5 \right) = \binom{5}{5} \left( \frac{91}{216} \right)^5 \left( \frac{125}{216} \right)^0 \\
\Rightarrow P \left( X_3 \geq 3 \right) = \frac{166845140826}{470184984576} = 0.35485$$
Your approach would work too, and can be useful in cases where the decision of which dice to reroll is less trivial. It's just that in this case there's an available simplification.

For a single die with rerolls for non-$6's$,
$P$(get a $6) = \frac16 + \frac56\frac16 + (\frac56)^2\frac16 =  \frac{91}{216} = p$ (say)
$P$(not get a $6) = 1-p = \frac{125}{216} = q$ (say)
Then $P$(get at least $3\;\; 6's$ from $5$ dice)
$$= \binom53p^3q^2 +\binom54p^4q + p^5$$
